# Laravel Homestead shared folder missing

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I've got Vagrant and Virtual Box installed. I'm in the process of trying to get Homestead working. My .yaml file looks like

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: C:/Users/GiggleSquid/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/GiggleSquid/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: 8Byte.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Projects/8Byte/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

But every time I run `vagrant up` in Git Bash, it throws an error

```
GiggleSquid@SQUID-RIG /d/Code/Homestead (master)
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you have already understand every fields's meaning in My.yaml otherwise, you will facing another error

Answer (score 1):

Exactly same answer to error log. You Code folder is missing in your  Windows environment. Create a folder name `Code` placed in `D:/`

Comment: I figured it out. I was editing the yaml file in the Homestead/src/stubs on my D drive. I didn't know there was one in my C drive under Users/GiggleSquid/.homestead

Answer (score 0):

You should check VirtualBox version. VirtualBox5.0 version doesn't work shard folder. it is working on VirtualBox 4.3 version.